# Add eventlistner dynamically using Jquery Ajax with dynamic page of laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, dynamic

I have divided my page in two parts. At left I am echoing All results with link and at right I want to display the result by clicking any link any time using Jquery Ajax.

My Blade code is ...

```
<div id="left" >
 <ul>

@foreach($url_data as $url)

    <input type="hidden" name="url_hits_id" value="{{url('dashboard'.'/'.$url->id)}}">
<li>
    <a class="show_hits">
         <p>{{$url->url}} </p>
         <p> {{'http//ucut.herokuapps.com/'.$url->key}}</p><br><hr>

    </a>
</li>

@endforeach

 </ul>

<div id ="right" style="float:left">

</div>
```

My Jquery code is ....

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var url = $('input[name=url_hits_id]').val();


$('.show_hits').click(function(){
    $.get(url,function(response){
           $('#right').html(response);
    });
   });


});
```

I want to display the result via ajax. I have one problem with my selector. It is only showing the result of the first `<li>` element, not all....I also want that at clicking anytime at any `<li>` tag I want the result of every tag. I have checked the all page individually (without Ajax). All are working fine.

Comment: Because all the inputs have same `name="url_hits_id"` and when you select one of them with jQuery selector, the click event happens for the first one.

Comment: But I am changing the url_hits_id dynamically and it is changing in the blade. please say me how to choose dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Change your blade like this:

```
@foreach($url_data as $url)

<input type="hidden" value="{{url('dashboard'.'/'.$url->id)}}">
<li>
    <a class="show_hits" onclick="submit({{url('dashboard'.'/'.$url->id)}});">
         <p>{{$url->url}} </p>
         <p> {{'http//ucut.herokuapps.com/'.$url->key}}</p><br><hr>
    </a>
</li>

@endforeach

<div id ="right" style="float:left"></div>
```

Then in your Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function submit(url){
        $.get(url,function(response){
             $('#right').html(response);
        });
    }
});
```

I didn't test it but I think it should work.
Let me know if it works :)

Comment: no its showing the error that in anchor tag line "caught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list."